# POST AN OBJECT that has two properties (an array and a object) to a webapi? - asp.net webpi

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api

I have a JSON Object that contains two objects

the first object is a json object called customer

and the second is a javascript array called dataserives

I have been trying to post these two objects to a webapia in the following format,

```
//this is the webapi method

public CustomerAndDataServices POST(CustomerAndDataServices cd)  
{
    return cd;    
}
```

and the JSON object I am posting is this

```
var customer ={name="clark"};

var dataservices=['email','internet', 'chat'];

var ds={''dataservices}

var data={

    customer:customer

    dataservices:ds

};

//this is how i post t  the webapi

$.ajax({

    url:'/api/myapi'

    data:{cd:dataservices}

});
```

//The problem is that whe I post this, the binding occurs on the customer object but the dataservices array is null.

I have seen how single arrays can be sent to a webapi  by making the property of the object assigned to the array an empty string

suhc as

```
$.ajax({

url:'/api/myapi'

data:{'':dataservices}

});
```

this solution works fine, but how can it work for my scenario where I am posting a json object whose properties are an object and an array?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 var customer = { name: "clark" };
 var dataservices = ['email', 'internet', 'chat'];

 //convert javascript object to JSON
 var cd = JSON.stringify({ customer: customer, dataservices: dataservices });

 $.ajax({
     url: '/api/myapi/',
     //declare ajax call is an HTTPPost
     method: 'POST',
     data: cd,
     //set data format as JSON
     contentType: 'application/json'
 });
```